# Why my program lags upon selecting strip

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have this function that calls the function:

```
private void liguaneaRxToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillLiguanea();
}
```

This is the function it invokes:

```
private void FillLiguanea()
{
    this.liguanea_LaneTableAdapter1.Fill(this.pharmaciesDataSet1.Liguanea_Lane);
    try
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Liguanea_Lane2";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string scode = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("code"));
            comboBox2.Items.Add(scode);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

It's over 5000+ data reading in from the SQL database, but a 20 second lag each time before it reads in will not be satisfying to the end user.

My question is why does this happen and is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: It would appear that it happens because that's how long it takes to execute the query and process the results.  Unless there's some easy optimization I'm missing, you may have to do some threading/async coding to avoid tying up the UI thread.

Comment: [Load data asynchronously into my DataTable in Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38427392/3110834)

Comment: Have you run that query in sql server managment studio ? how does it performs there ? If it also takes 20 seconds there than you have your answer.

Comment: It takes less than a second to run in MSSQL so I don't believe that is the issue

Comment: Small thing: You are not closing your connection after it's done. You might want to do that to avoid memory leaks! I do not think it's the source of your problems. You might want to wrap your sql connection in a using statement so you don't have to write that logic

Comment: Also as another tuning, you should call `comboBox2.BeginUpdate()` before while and `comboBox2.EndUpdate()` after loop or use `Items.AddRange` instead [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39338415/3110834).

Comment: ok so you are running this `string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Liguanea_Lane2";` but you are only loading the comboBox2 with `code` then either change your query to `select on Code from Liguanea` or bind the code to a `List<T>`

Comment: @RezaAghaei Am assuming you meant comboBox2

Comment: @MethodMan did that before and didn't improve performance. Binding it into a List that is

Comment: @Jevon Yes, or whatever the combo box is.

Comment: Correcting the way of adding items to combo box will have an impressive impact on performance. See the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338237/populate-listbox-with-a-ienumrable-on-another-thread-winforms)

Comment: what about selecting only the Code to speed up the performance..? have you tied that as well @Jevon ?

Comment: It might also be because the ArithAbort property on your database is off. See also http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: @GuidoG  thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: @Jevon So you are saying that executing the query in your code also takes less than a second ?

Comment: @GuidoG in my code it takes 20 seconds. In MSSQL it takes less than a second. Am guessing it has something to do with reading so much data from the MSSQL table am dealing with. Just need to speed that up. Wondering if adding a "loading,please wait" could be a work around

Comment: @Jevon Wat exactly is taking 20 seconds ? You should check if the code cmd.ExecuteReader(); takes 20 seconds or the loop after it. Put a breakpoint on SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); and than measure how long it takes when you press F10. If this takes 20 seconds than the link in my prior comment is your solution, if not than there is something in your c# code not correct. Also check with a profiler what command is send to the database.

Comment: Did the problem get solved?

Comment: No, the lag is expected because it is reading in 10k + records, so am trying to implement a background worker. I just posted my attempt. your input on it would be good

Comment: I really will not use a background worker if I write code in .NET 4.5. Surely using async/await pattern is preferred.

Comment: oh am not familiar with it. Your input would be great though on my new question with the async/await. I don't really fancy background worker

Comment: @RezaAghaei could you help me out please? no one seems to have any solution

Comment: I honestly didn't see that you asked that. My apologies. Am looking at your current response now

Comment: Does the end user really need 5000+ data in one combobox?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov it has to because based on the selection from that it populates the textBox that follows with values from the SQL Database. It's basically an inventory program

Comment: @RezaAghaei am gonna post my updated code blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider some notes to make the form run without being frozen.

1. You should load data in another thread. You can create a `Thread`, or use `BackgroundWorker` or using `async/await` pattern like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38427392/3110834).
2. You are adding items to `ListBox` one by one using `listBox.Items.Add()`. If you want to do so, at least you should call `listBox.BeginUpdate()` before adding the loop and call `listBox.EndUpdate()` after the loop. It makes an impressive impact on your UI. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338237/populate-listbox-with-a-ienumrable-on-another-thread-winforms) for more information. You can call `AddRange` or set the `DataSource`. Setting data source will work great.

**Example**

```
public async Task<DataTable> GetDataAsync()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    var cn = @"Your Connection String";
    var cmd = @"SELECT Field1 FROM Table1";
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, cn);
    await Task.Run(() => { da.Fill(dt); });
    return dt;
}   
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = await GetDataAsync();
    this.ListBox1.DataSource = data;
    this.ListBox1.DisplayMember= "Field1";
}
```

Comment: I saw it. The answer which I posted is not based on backgroundworker and it's totally different. Try it and let us the result.

Comment: Am not quite understanding the <Data Table> part. Those arguments inside should be replaced by my "fillLiguanea()" function parameters?

Comment: No it shouldn't be replaced. Just replace your query and your connection string. Try to learn something new. It's really better to load data this way.  `var cn = @"Data Source=LPMSW09000012JD\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pharmacies;Integrated Security=True""`

Comment: `var cmd = @"SELECT Code FROM dbo.Liguanea_Lane2"` and `this.ListBox1.DisplayMember= "Code";`

Comment: These are all changes you need to make the code working for yourself.

Comment: Use only one \ since we used `@` behind the string. Also you don't need to select `*`, code would be enough.

Comment: It's in general OK. By the way, don't edit the question with updated code, it makes the answers nonsense :)

Comment: Ok I will remember tha in the future. An exception is being thrown by "da.Fill(dt))"

Comment: What's the exception? did you corrected the connection string as I said use one \?

Comment: Yes I did correct it. It works now but this isn't what am looking for. It is doing what it has been doing from the beginning. What I want is for it to load the data based on the dropdown selected in comboBox4.

Comment: eg: if(comboBox4.selectedIndex==0{

//do stuff

}

Comment: Surely it's better than what you had at first. Now it doesn't freeze.

Comment: But it wasn't freezing before. it only froze when conditional operators were introduced. Like the strip menu or a comboBox. It always loaded fast. it just froze and move slow cause conditions were introduced.

Comment: No problem. It seems you need to read more about How to ask. We can't predict and read what is in your mind. Currently the question talks about a freezing issue which can be solved by the answer

Comment: I'm interested to help. I think it's better to ask a new question based on the current code and clearly say what is the problem now (which is not freezing at all). I think you need to fill the data table using parameters, for example *SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Id = 1* and 1 would be a value fromm the combo box. Any way, it's just a guess. Your description about the problem and the codes will be required :)

Comment: Also if you want to fill a DataTable using a TableAdapter asynchronously use `var ds = new DataSet1(); await Task.Run(() =>{ tableAdapter1.Fill(ds.Table1);});` The same way which is used in `GetDataAsync` for a data adapter.

Comment: If you learn more about `async/await` life would be easier. As you see also others guide you to use `async/await` instead of `backgroundworker` :)

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to have more than one sql table populate in data grid based on an if condition?

Comment: You can load any count of DataTable of a DataSet and return the DataSet. Also you can Load data tables one by one asynchronously. The core line of code is here `await Task.Run(() => { da.Fill(dt); });`.

Comment: Then if you specifically asking about `DataGridView` it's enough to set its `DataSource` to a `DataTable` based on a criteria.

Comment: OHHH brilliant. Thanks. You are an awesome tutor

Comment: @Jevon By the way, it seems the post answers your question and it would be great if you accept/upvote the post :) It's not compulsory at all.